# Azure data factory disaster recovery

Tags: azure-data-factory

How does Azure Data Factory (ADFv2) handle disaster recovery (DR) in the integration runtime? Will it automatically create another integration runtime? Do we have to setup our own DR "Azure-SSIS Integration Runtime"

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, there is no disaster recovery feature available with Integration runtime. If service stops due to any error, you will have to manually restart the service.

You should ideally setup multiple nodes for Integration Runtime. Link below points to section on High Availability and Scalability, with details on setting up multiple nodes (upto 4).

This avoids having a single point of failure and provides higher throughput, as all nodes are setup as active.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime#high-availability-and-scalability

Answer (score 0):

ADF V2 support stopping the SSIS integration runtime in the current region and switch to another region ([Paired-region](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/best-practices-availability-paired-regions) is recommended) to start it again.

To support that,

- You need to make sure that you have enabled your azure SQL server DR in case the azure sql server has outage at the same time.
- You may need to prepare another vNet that could be connected to your azure sql server if you have are using VNet.
- You may need to prepare your customer script SAS Uri which could be accessed during outage if you are using custom script.

Then you can follow these steps to switch your IR to the new region and start it again.

- Stop the IR in the original region.
- Call following command in PowerShell to update the integration runtime

  `` Set-AzureRmDataFactoryV2IntegrationRuntime -Location "new region" `
                                         -CatalogServerEndpoint "SQL Server endpoint" `
                                         -CatalogAdminCredential "credential" `
                                         -VNetId "new VNet" `
                                         -Subnet "new subnet" `
                                         -SetupScriptContainerSasUri "new script SAS Uri" ``
- Start the IR again.

About how to use PowerShell command, please refer to [Create the Azure-SSIS integration runtime in Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-azure-ssis-integration-runtime) for more details.

Comment: Thanks Layla. Could you also let me know if we can setup DR for "AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime"?

Comment: SSIS integration doesn't have AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime now.